# Set default date based on date other date column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column, date-time

I'm fairly new to SharePoint and I'm still learning the terminology so please excuse

I have 2 Date Time columns in a SharePoint list, `Date Received` and `Due Date`. The `Due Date` is supposed to be 30 days from the `Date Received` date. If I make the `Due Date` a Calculated Column, it's fairly straightforward.

```
=[Date Received] + 30
```

However, calculated columns can't be modified by users. In this case, I need to allow users to change the `Due Date` column which isn't and make the default value for the `Due Date` using the Calculated Value option. My issue is that an error occurs when I try to use the same formula in the Calculated Value input box. Is it not possible to reference other columns in a formula to calculate the default value of a Date column?

Answer (score 1):

A default value formula cannot reference another column because the list form does not support a dynamic recalculation of the default formula.

If you need to set a default value based on another column, and still have that user editable, you can use InfoPath to customise the form, or if you don't have that, use Javascript / jQuery to set the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workflow to handle this. The workflow should start on item update.

Use an if condition to check

```
if currentitem:DateReceived equals empty
     Update currentitem:DueDate = currentitem:DateReceived + 30
```

I used following to get this working in both New and Edit use cases

[image]

`Variable: date` - This should be string type and `CurrentItem:DueDate` should return `ShortDate`

`Variable: date1` - This should be date time type.

`Update` - This should set current item `DueDate` with value in `variable: date1`

Comment: that does not help while the user is editing the form, though.

Comment: @teylyn how this approach will not work in edit cases? I have updated my answer with the workflow steps

Comment: the workflow will only kick in after the item is saved. Then the user can open it again and see the calculated value. As I understand the question, dspencer wants the field to be showing the calculated default value dynamically, while the form is being edited. So, user loads a new form. DueDate is blank. User edits DateReceived and now DueDate immediately shows the calculated value, which the user can edit. Then the user saves. Workflows can't do that. Javascript or InfoPath can.

Comment: @teylyn Yes, that is the correct behaviour I would like to achieve. Amal's solution does work as it does add 30 days to the Due Date field but as you mentioned, it's not the optimal user experience as the user would technically have to save the item and then view the item to see the Due Date  column value.